# Adonis isn't migrating

Tags: mysql-workbench, knex.js, adonis.js

I've installed mysql npm in my adonis project and also set **DB_CONNECTION=mysql** in .env.

Everything in my .env is correct, but when i run the migration cmd i get an error.

```
 code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
 errno: 1045,
 sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES)",
 sqlState: '28000',
 fatal: true
```

I don't have any clue whats going on, i google the error but no solution was found.

And why its saying **'root'@'172.17.0.1'** if localhost is 127.0.0.1?

What should i do?

Comment: Try to change (on your `.env`) `DB_HOST` to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR means it can't authenticate to db : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232953/error-access-denied-for-user-localhost-using-password-no

Comment: Do you have a password for the db?

Comment: please put your .env file

Comment: We can't help you if you don't answer our questions...

Answer (score 4):

As the error message implies, you're having an authorization problem.

You said that your .env file is correct, but double check if it contains the following variables:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 //make sure it's your localhost
DB_PORT= //usually 3306
DB_USER=
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_DATABASE=
```

Then, check if your `config/database.js` file is properly calling the .env variables, without any typo or missmatched name.

If it is all fine and the problem continues, he i suggest you to check your database credentials.

Try acessing it without password, since some default configurations to mysql databases uses the username `root` and an empty password. (in the error message you received a `(using password: YES)`)

If you double checked all that and are still getting this error, I recommend you to create another Database User with root privileges.